# Concatenation of arrays and their conversion to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the next PostgreSQL query:

```sql
WITH sub_query AS (
    SELECT vi.idvalfield,
           vi.value::text
    FROM valueint_value AS vi
    UNION
    SELECT vt.idvalfield,
           vt.value::text
    FROM valuetext_value AS vt
)


SELECT
       sq.idvalfield,
       sq.value
FROM sub_query AS sq
         JOIN valuefield AS vf ON vf.idvalfield = sq.idvalfield
         JOIN event e on vf.idevent = e.idevent
WHERE NOT (e.idevent || array[]::uuid[]) && (SELECT array_agg(e.idevent) AS id_event
                                              FROM sub_query AS sq
                                                       JOIN valuefield AS vf ON vf.idvalfield = sq.idvalfield
                                                       JOIN event e on vf.idevent = e.idevent
                                              WHERE (idtable = 41 AND sq.value = 222)
                                                 OR (idtable = 43 AND sq.value = 18)
);
```

I described the construction of `WITH`. The number of tables in UNION is dynamic:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_
from sqlalchemy import cast, Table, Text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array_agg, array, ARRAY, UUID

models_view = [
        session.query(
            model.c.idvalfield.label('id_value'),
            cast(model.c.value, Text).label('value')
        ).filter(model.c.idvalfield.in_(id_fields))
        for model, id_fields in model_values.items()
    ]

cte_union_view = models_view[0].union_all(*models_view[1:]).cte()
```

Described a subquery in WHERE:

```py
filtered_event = session.query(array_agg(Event.idevent))\
        .select_from(cte_union_view)\
        .join(Valuefield, cte_union_view.c.id_value == Valuefield.idvalfield)\
        .join(Event, Event.idevent == Valuefield.idevent)\
        .filter(or_(and_(Valuefield.idtable == 41, cte_union_view.c.value == '222'),
                    and_(Valuefield.idtable == 43, cte_union_view.c.value == '18'))).subquery()
```

Described the main request:

```py
event_all = session.query(cte_union_view)\
        .join(Valuefield, cte_union_view.c.id_value == Valuefield.idvalfield)\
        .join(Event, Event.idevent == Valuefield.idevent).all()
```

But I can't describe the selection condition in any way:

```sql
WHERE NOT (e.idevent || array[]::uuid[]) && (SELECT array_agg(e.idevent)
```

I try:

```py
filter(cast([Event.idevent + array([])], ARRAY(UUID)).in_(filtered_event))
and 
filter(cast([array([Event.idevent]) + array([])], ARRAY(UUID)).in_(filtered_event))
```

But I don't know how to describe it

Comment: Why not just make life easy and ditch the ORM? You can still get many of the other benefits of SQLAlchemy, and avoid the whole issue.

Comment: @Z4-tier This query should return filtered table rows. Different tables. Therefore, it must be dynamic. In addition, it is an EAV database. At the time of writing the CTE query, I don't know how many tables there should be and which ones. And it's probably more difficult to find it on the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Maybe it will be useful to someone.
Converting a UUID to an array of UUID's:

```sql
(e.idevent || array[]::uuid[])
```

you can do this using `literal_column`:

```py
literal_column('ARRAY[]::uuid[]').op('||')(Event.idevent)
```

And now the whole `WHERE ' block can be described like this:

```py
.filter(uuid_event_arr.notin_(filtered_event)).all()
```

But, in fact, it was easier to rewrite the subquery in `WHERE`, without the 'array_agg ()' function. This in turn makes it easier to build a query using alchemy:

```py
filtered_event = session.query(Event.idevent)\
        .select_from(cte_union_view)\
        .join(Valuefield, cte_union_view.c.id_value == Valuefield.idvalfield)\
        .join(Event, Event.idevent == Valuefield.idevent)\
        .filter(and_(Valuefield.idtable == 41, cte_union_view.c.v_text == '222'))

views_value = session.query(cte_union_view)\
        .join(Valuefield, cte_union_view.c.id_value == Valuefield.idvalfield)\
        .join(Event, Event.idevent == Valuefield.idevent)\
        .filter(Event.idevent.in_(filtered_event)).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also: `array(tuple_(Event.idevent), type_=UUID)`